# Scipy. Import Error: cannot import name multivariate_normal

Tags: python, scipy

I am running python 2.7.5 with scipy 0.13.0b1 on OSX. I have ran 'pip install scipy --upgrade' and it says I am using the latest version, yet when I try to import multivariate_normal I still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.stats.multivariate_normal` was [only introduced in 0.14.0](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/release.0.14.0.html#scipy-stats-improvements)

For upgrading, if you want `pip` to install the latest `scipy` package, you might need to upgrade your Python first (the latest version is 2.7.9).

Personally, I find life is much easier with [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) and the `conda` package manager.

Comment: That is exactly what I have been using - without much luck.

Comment: My bad -- here's a better answer.

Comment: How do I install 0.14.0 or above for python 2.7.5? I have tried using 'pip install scipy --upgrade' and it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2909415, this is unclear now,  are you only using pip or is your comment above indicating that  you used or use Anaconda?

Comment: @PhilCooper I have never used Anaconda nor do I know what it is, should I be using it?